# Openpyxl - Empty Cells being added when copy and pasting data

Tags: python, excel, copy, openpyxl, paste

My script copies data from each sheet from one excel workbook to the first sheet in another workbook. The script will also sort the data based on the value in column A.

My issue is that my current output is adding empty cells between data. I'm not sure why this is happening. Does anyone know why? Thank you.

[image]

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = load_workbook('testData.xlsx')
wb2 = load_workbook('testTemplate.xlsx')

get_sheet = wb.sheetnames

for sheet in get_sheet:
    
    ws = wb[sheet]
    mr = ws.max_row
    mc = ws.max_column

    ws2 = wb2['Sheet1']
    mr2 = ws2.max_row
    mc2 = ws2.max_column

    for i in range(2, mr + 2):
        for j in range(1, mc + 1):
            if ws.cell(row=i,column=j).value == "A":
                ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j).value = ws.cell(row=i,column=j+1).value
            elif ws.cell(row=i,column=j).value == "B":
                ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j+1).value = ws.cell(row=i,column=j+1).value
            elif ws.cell(row=i,column=j).value == "C":
                ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j+2).value = ws.cell(row=i,column=j+1).value
                mr2 += 1

wb2.save('testTemplate.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Debugging your code finally got the point you are applying `mr2 += 1` when Value = C and you giving enter after value of C comes.

Code which solve your problem:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = load_workbook('testData.xlsx')
wb2 = load_workbook('testTemplate.xlsx')

get_sheet = wb.sheetnames

for sheet in get_sheet:
    
    ws = wb[sheet]
    mr = ws.max_row
    mc = ws.max_column

    ws2 = wb2['Sheet1']
    mr2 = ws2.max_row
    mc2 = ws2.max_column

    for i in range(2, mr + 2):
        for j in range(1, mc + 1):
            if ws.cell(row=i,column=j).value == "A":
                ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j).value = ws.cell(row=i,column=j+1).value
                # check wheater B or C column has black space if not do mr2 += 1
                if ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j+1).value !=None:
                    if ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j+2).value!=None:
                        mr2 += 1
            elif ws.cell(row=i,column=j).value == "B":
                ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j+1).value = ws.cell(row=i,column=j+1).value
                # check wheater A or C column has black space if not do mr2 += 1
                if ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j).value !=None:
                    if ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j+2).value!=None:
                        mr2 += 1
            elif ws.cell(row=i,column=j).value == "C":
                ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j+2).value = ws.cell(row=i,column=j+1).value
                # check wheater A or B column has black space if not do mr2 += 1
                if ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j).value !=None:
                    if ws2.cell(row=mr2 + 1,column=j+1).value!=None:
                        mr2 += 1

wb2.save('testTemplate.xlsx')
```

Let me know if this helps you

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. Just so I understand, you are saying that when the for loop reaches Value = C, I was telling the script to add an empty cell?

Comment: Exactly, try to debug your program to understand more perfectly.

Comment: Are you suffering from any problem? Any special reason to unaccept my answer?

Comment: Apologies, was an accident.

Comment: Hello, I adjusted my script to use iter_row, and the solution no longer works, would you be able to assist?

Comment: I had [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74293284/openpyxl-empty-rows-when-copy-and-pasting-data/74299743#74299743) your question