# Openpyxl - Empty rows when copy and pasting data

Tags: python, excel, copy, openpyxl, paste

I've written a script which copies data from one workbook to another. My only issue is that empty cells are being added between data. Can anyone understand why? It looks like the script is skipping values which don't meet the condition of the if statement, but still copying a blank cell.

[image]

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = load_workbook('testData.xlsx')
wb2 = load_workbook('testTemplate.xlsx')

ws = wb.worksheets[0]
mr = ws.max_row

ws2 = wb2.worksheets[0]
mr2 = ws2.max_row

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row = 1, min_col = 1, max_row = mr, max_col = 3):
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == "A":
            ws2.cell(row = mr2 + 1, column = 1).value = (cell.offset(column = + 1).value)
            mr2 += 1
        elif cell.value == "B":
            ws2.cell(row = mr2 + 1, column = 2).value = (cell.offset(column = + 1).value)
            mr2 += 1
        elif cell.value == "C":
            ws2.cell(row = mr2 + 1, column = 3).value = (cell.offset(column = + 1).value)
            mr2 += 1

wb2.save('testTemplate.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your issue:

Giving Enter(mr2 += 1) every time after entering value as it return in if condition

### Solution:

Create separate counter for different columns and Enter(Counter += 1) when value in entered in that column

As per example:

```
A = ws2.max_row
if cell.value == "A":
   ws2.cell(row = A + 1, column = 1).value = (cell.offset(column = + 1).value)
   A += 1
```

### Full Code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = load_workbook('testData.xlsx')
wb2 = load_workbook('testTemplate.xlsx')

ws = wb.worksheets[0]
mr = ws.max_row

ws2 = wb2.worksheets[0]
A = ws2.max_row
B = ws2.max_row
C = ws2.max_row

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row = 2, min_col = 1, max_row = mr, max_col = 2):
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == "A":
            ws2.cell(row = A + 1, column = 1).value = (cell.offset(column = + 1).value)
            A += 1
        elif cell.value == "B":
            ws2.cell(row = B + 1, column = 2).value = (cell.offset(column = + 1).value)
            B +=1
        elif cell.value == "C":   
            ws2.cell(row = C + 1, column = 3).value = (cell.offset(column = + 1).value)
            C +=1

wb2.save('testTemplate.xlsx')
```