# How to append and skip empty cells in excel when using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I am trying to create an app that logs data from the app to an excel sheet. I want to append certain data in specific columns but it skips every line that has data on other columns as shown in the picture
[image]

For this I use the code:

```
ID = len(sheet['ID'])
data = [ID, MedS.get(), QuanS.get(),HosS.get(),ExpS.get(), time_stamp]      
sheet.append(data)
```

I'd like the result to look like this picture
[image]
How would I append the data without skipping empty rows?

Comment: think you should not append Len of sheet but just create a loop from there

Comment: you can refer my [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74293284/openpyxl-empty-rows-when-copy-and-pasting-data/74299743#74299743) or [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74263738/openpyxl-empty-cells-being-added-when-copy-and-pasting-data/74266131#74266131)